# loading content from another php page into index php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a **#container1** div on **index.php**.
I am trying to load **#container1** with the contents of a **#container2** div from **page1.php**.
I cannot figure out why this isn't working.

My file hierarchy is like this:

```
Project

 -Js
  --myJs

 -index.php
 -page1.php
```

**index.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl">
    <head>
    <base href="..\project\">
        <title></title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Assistant" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"  />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/myJs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**page1.php**

```
<!doctype html>

    <head>
    <base href="..\project\">
        <title></title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Assistant" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"  />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/myJs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container2">
            <div id="hello" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue;">
                <p>hello<p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myJs.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#container").load("../page1.php #container2> *");
});
```

**index** otherwise shows up just fine. when I manually put the div **#hello** into **#container1** it displays perfectly.
**page1** also shows up well.

debugging didn't tell me much. the code successfully stepped into the function, but the **hello** is just not showing up.
the console is empty.

Comment: It looks like you're executing the JavaScript on `page1.php` but *meant* to execute it on `index.php`.

Comment: `$("#container").load("../page1.php #container2");` Does that work?

Comment: putting hashtage with id name doesn't mean that it will only pick the div data, it means that page will focus on that div.

Comment: you have to use javascript DOM. Load the whole html of page1.php and insert in DOM and then pick the content of `container2`.

Comment: @anujarora: That's what `.load()` does behind the scenes already: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @anujarora, I don't have enough background in this to know what you mean. Is it possible for you to elaborate?

Comment: @David,  I edited my question, to include more of my index page

Comment: @JustCarty, tried that. doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery Slim which does not contain any AJAX functionality.
To rectify your problem you need to include the *full* jQuery library and change the jQuery code slightly.

Replace your jQuery script tag with the following:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then, in myJs.js, change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#container").load("../page1.php #container2");
});
```

Notice that I have changed the string from `../page1.php #container2> *` to what it is above. <strike>CSS selectors cannot be used in that way in the load function, instead you can just target one element.</strike>

The other thing you might need to do is remove the `<base>` tag. That's playing havoc with relative URLs.
The console will then tell you the problem `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function`.

Comment: I changed the jquery library to the min version you suggested. I removed the base, like you said, but still nothings happening... the console is still not showing any errors. debugging shows that the myJs is being performed.

Comment: I tried the selectors, and they actually work too. I guess it was the slim version that was causing the problem, like you said.

Comment: @Jay If you wanted to only load certain modules then you can look at something like this: https://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ Which allows you to only load modules you need to reduce jQuery. That is, of course, if you loaded slim to save space and not just by accident.